# incompatible pointer types passing 'void (void *) to parameter of type 'void *

Tags: c, pthreads

I have created pthread as follows:

```
void function1(void *s) {
start = (*(int *)s ;
}

pthread_t threads[numthreads];
int ids[numthreads];
for (i = 0; i < numthreads; i++) {
    ids[i] = i;
    int * p = &ids[i] ;
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, function1, (void *)p);
}
```

But this is giving me error:

```
>> mpicc -o hprogram hprogram.c
warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'void (void *)' to
      parameter of type 'void * _Nullable (* _Nonnull)(void * _Nullable)'
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
                        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, function1, (void *)...
                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/pthread.h:328:31: note: passing argument to parameter here
                void * _Nullable (* _Nonnull)(void * _Nullable),
                                            ^
1 warning generated.
```

This is an mpi program and im creating a hybrid mpi using pthreads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pthread_create()` expects a pointer to a function that takes a `void*` as input and returns a `void*` as output, but your function returns a `void` instead.  You just need to add a `*` to the return type, and add a `return` statement, eg:

```
void* function1(void *s) {
    start = *(int *)s;
    return NULL; // <-- or whatever you want
}
```